# How to solve this error "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the same object in two differebt dbContext. I got this error

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

What are the possible causes of this error?

```
public string ValidateNXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY(int id)
{
    long? ValCounter = 0;
    string prepQu = Constante.CurrentUser.LOG_USER; ;
    DateTime dateQu = DateTime.Today;
    NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY module = new NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY();

    try
    {
        using (CaseManagerEntities db = new CaseManagerEntities())
        {                    
            NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY cmd = db.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY.Find(id);                    
            module = cmd;
        }                

        using (PHStockEntities db = new PHStockEntities())
        {
            using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
            {
                NXT_PH_COUNTER Counter = db.NXT_PH_COUNTER.Where(nat => nat.TYPE_CHOIX == 301).First();
                ValCounter = Counter.Value;
                Counter.Value = ValCounter + 1;                        

                foreach (var detail in module.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY_DETAIL.ToList())
                {

                    NXT_PH_CHOIX_MODULE choix = db.NXT_PH_CHOIX_MODULE.Where(nat => nat.TYPE_CHOIX == 301).First();
                    NXT_ASS_ART_LOT_DEP_EC association = db.NXT_ASS_ART_LOT_DEP_EC.Where(nat => nat.ID_ARTICLE == detail.ID_LIST_PH_DET && nat.ID_LIST_DEPOT == module.DEPOT).First();

                    decimal? QTE = 0;
                    if (choix.SIGNE_STOCK == "P")
                    {
                        QTE = detail.QTE_PH_DET;
                    }
                    else if (choix.SIGNE_STOCK == "M")
                    {
                        QTE = decimal.Negate(decimal.Parse(detail.QTE_PH_DET.ToString()));
                    }
                    switch (choix.CHAMP_STOCK)
                    {
                        case "STOCK_VENTE":
                            association.STOCK_VENTE = association.STOCK_VENTE + QTE;
                            break;
                        case "STOCK_ACHAT":
                            association.STOCK_ACHAT = association.STOCK_ACHAT + QTE;
                            break;
                        case "STOCK_MOUVEMENT":
                            association.STOCK_MOUVEMENT = association.STOCK_MOUVEMENT + QTE;
                            break;
                        case "STOCK_ETAGE":
                            association.STOCK_ETAGE = association.STOCK_ETAGE + QTE;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                t.Complete();
            }
        }

        using (CaseManagerEntities db = new CaseManagerEntities())
        {
            using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
            {
                module.NBR_QUITTANCE = ValCounter.ToString();
                module.DATE_QUITTANCE = dateQu;
                module.PREPART_QUITTANCE = prepQu;
                module.STATUT = 3;
                dbCaseManager.SaveChanges();
                t.Complete();
            }
        }
        return ValCounter.ToString() + ";" + prepQu + ";" + dateQu.Date;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "ERROR";
    }        
}
```

Comment: the exception is thrown in "foreach (var detail in module.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY_DETAIL.ToList())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are disposing of `CaseManagerEntities` in the first using statement, so any further lazy loading of                     navigation properties is trying to fetch the data using a disposed context. One way to solve this would be to eager load the entities you require. Assuming that the primary key on `NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY` is id, try this:

```
var cmd = db.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY.Include(x => x.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY_DETAIL).Single(x => x.id == id);
```

Comment: i had this error : NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY does not contain a definition for "Include"

Comment: Sorry I got the order wrong, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Now i got this error : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code...

```
using (CaseManagerEntities db = new CaseManagerEntities())
{                    
    NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY cmd = db.NXT_MODULE_DETAILS_PHARMACY.Find(id);
    module = cmd;
}
```

...creates the `module` and immediately disposes the context it's connected with. Afterwards, your trying to lazy load `module`'s members, which requires a live context.

You have to move the closing brace to the bottom of your code, just before the `return` statement.

Another issue is that later on, you modify `module`, but call `SaveChanges()` on `dbCaseManager` - whatever that is, it's not the context that tracks `module`. So `module` is not saved.

Side note: do yourself a favor and don't use these awful capitalized/prefixed/underscored names that probably bubbled up directly from database names. The idea of an O/R *mapper* is that you can map more friendly names to these database names that for whatever reason often seem to have to look like these monsters.

Further: these `TransactionScope`s are useless. `SaveChanges` manages its own transaction: it either succeeds or rolls back everything it tries to submit.